# Using the moment.js to check the time on an element is not working

Tags: javascript, cypress, momentjs, importerror

I need to check the time on element is the current time plus two hours.  I found some suggestions, but I cannot get it to work.

This is my current code:

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
    const newTime = moment().add(+2, 'h').format('HH:mm')
    cy.get('[for="timefrom"]').should('be.visible').and('have.text', 'Time from: ')
    cy.get('#timefrom').should('be.visible').and('have.value', newTime)
})
```

and I have placed the `moment.js` file in my folder and imported it

```
import {} from "./moment.js";
```

When I run my test, I am getting the following error

> moment is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your import:

```
import{
   
} from "./moment.js";
```

mean as much as:

```
import *nothing* from "./moment.js";
```

Thus when calling any moment-function you get an error.

What you need is:

```
import moment from "./moment.js";
```

That way, you import the entire moment module.

"*What are the brackets for?*", one might ask. The curled brackets `{}` are used, when you want to use only specific parts of a module and reduce the build size for production.

E.g: You have a module with 100 function, but you only need three of them, then you do the following:

```
import {fancyFunction, awesomeFunction, mediocreFunction} from "./module.js";
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  thats now working and you just taught me something i didnt know.  really appreciate it :)